# socket.io failing after refresh page in client side

Tags: node.js, reactjs, sockets, websocket, socket.io

I am using socket.io in a react - node project. I have a problem with the socket not refreshing when the page refreshes.

It works first as the server and the react dev server run for the first time. After using the socket ( emitting something from the server ), refreshing the browser page would result in an error in the web socket.js file :

> WebSocket connection to
>   'ws://localhost:4000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket&sid=XTE63CeWdp676cRXAAAF'
>   failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code:
>   400

here is the code I use in client and server :

**SERVER :**

```
const express = require('express');
const socketconfig = require('./socket.io');
class Server {
  constructor({ config, router, logger,  }) {
    this.config = config;
    this.logger = logger;
    this.express = express();
    this.express.disable('x-powered-by');
    this.express.use(router);
  }

  start() {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {

      const http = this.express
        .listen(this.config.web.port, () => {
          const { port } = http.address();
          this.logger.info(`[p ${process.pid}] Listening at port ${port}`);
          resolve();
        });
      var io = require('socket.io').listen(http,function () {
        console.log("I AM CONNECTIONG")
      });
      this.freshio=io.sockets;

      socketconfig.setOnConnection(this.freshio, ()=>{
        console.log('Connexion COnditions are set');
      });
      socketconfig.setOnDisconnect(this.freshio, ()=>{
        console.log('client disconnected');
      });
      this.clients = socketconfig.clients;
    });
  }
}

module.exports = Server;
```

the `start()` method would be called when the server is initiated. 
the `socketConfig` file is just a toolkit for saving clients and setting conditions, it doesn't interfere with anything.

**CLIENT :**

```
import openSocket from 'socket.io-client';

let url = Store.config.socketserverurl + ":" + Store.config.socketserverport;
const socket = openSocket.connect(url);
```

Store is just the flux store that has the config files linked to it.

I have tried adding the webSockets method of using socket.io instead of the http method but that was in vain as an other problem spiraled.

what should I do ?

Comment: Did you find a solution ?

Comment: @UzumakiNaruto I added a second HTTP server and ran the socket on that, just like the documentation said. it fixed my problems.